# How to do a sbt-(local)multi-project without the same project-root?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, dependencies, sbt, multi-project

I want to work on multiple sbt-projects at the same time in intellij. The projects are "one way dependent", meaning that one is the (reusable) core and the other is an actual application built upon that core. Both are currently in development.

I want the core to reside in another base/root-directory than the application, so:

```
- /core
-- build.sbt

- /application
-- build.sbt
```

I want to be able to

1. modify both projects in the same IntelliJ-window
2. leave both projects in their respective folder (no wrapper-folder around them!). Core will be used in other applications as well, applications that are **no** siblings to the current "application", so I do **not want** them to reside under the same root-folder!

What I've tried and which problems I've found so far:

setups like

```
lazy val core = project.in(file("../core"))
lazy val application = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(core)
```

are not working, because an sbt asserts that the directory of each project in a multi-project-setup are contained in the same build root:

> sbt
>   java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Directory /core is not contained in build root /application

setups like

```
lazy val core = RootProject(file("../core"))
lazy val application = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(core)
```

are not a solution because:

1. I can **not** have both projects in one IntelliJ-window then
2. Strangely the classes of core are not found in application, although
   the imports worked right away

Now I am a sbt-newbie and I guess (and hope) that there must be a solution for this problem. I can't be the only one wanting to separate my projects without a wrapper-layer and still be able to modify them in the IDE of my choice.

**edit:**

@OlegRudenko´s solution is semi-working for me. As `core` has some dependencies as well, I cannot compile or work with it in `application`.

`core` pulls in some dependencies like e.g. a Logger and when I'm in `application` and try to use a component of `core` the compiler screams at me, because it can't find the dependencies in `core` (e.g. the logger).

Also, `core` pulls in e.g. lwjgl and I want to use some components of it in `application`, no chance, because it can't find the packages for that dependency of `core`.

For now what I do is a hacky non-solution. I just develop both `core` and `application` in the same intellij-project and keep the git-repo private.

This is not a solution at all, as I want to open source `core` while `application` is closed source for now and I still want to work on both at the same time, refine the `core` etc.

Comment: I would make inside your root project a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to the `core`, which will be kept at its original place. Can you do so?

Comment: @OlegRudenko: Yes, but that would mean manually managing it on every machine I work one. As the project(s) will go open source one day it's kind of tedious to assume the same of every developer :(

Comment: the folder structure should be same on all machines. So, if, for example, SBT Build File will create the symbolic link automatically, then it could be a solution for your need. Right? If yes, I will investigate it to provide details as an answer.

Comment: @OlegRudenko: Yes, if it is the same on every Operating System it would be fine by me.

Comment: @Teolha take a look at the project organization I use for my projects https://github.com/alexandrnikitin/netty-scala-template/tree/master/project

Comment: @AlexandrNikitin What exactly should I see there?

Comment: This is one of the correct times to use git submodules.

Comment: @pfn: How is a `git submodule` helping with my (separated) directory-structure?

Comment: The point is you don't, you create a top-level project which is the outer git container, and git submodules for each core and app project. core and app don't know each other, other than app depending on core. The git trees are completely independent, which seems to be your overall goal. (being able to keep one open-source while the other is not)

Comment: Then again I would need an other container, which is not really what I'd prefer... but alas, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 7):

If some framework does not allow me something, I prefer to not fight but to find a compromise.

SBT does not allow to have a sub-project outside of project root.
So my solution would be to create a symbolic link inside my project to the sub-project, which is located outside:

```
common/
common/core/  - I want this as a sub-project inside of my project
application/
application/ui/  - This is my project

application/ui/core/ -> ../../common/core/  - This is my goal
```

It has to

- work automatically
- work on different operating systems
- be clear and understandable
- use standard tools

Solution is to add following lines into the SBT file:

```
val __createLinkToCore = {
  import java.nio.file.{FileSystemException, Files, Paths}
  import scala.util.Try

  val corePath = Paths.get("..", "..", "common", "core")
  if(!Files.exists(corePath)) throw new IllegalStateException("Target path does not exist")

  val linkPath = Paths.get("core")
  if(Files.exists(linkPath)) Files.delete(linkPath)

  Try {Files.createSymbolicLink(linkPath, corePath)}.recover {
    case cause: FileSystemException if System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase.contains("windows") =>
      val junctionCommand = Array("cmd", "/c", "mklink", "/J", linkPath.toAbsolutePath.normalize().toString, corePath.toAbsolutePath.normalize().toString)
      val junctionResult = new java.lang.ProcessBuilder(junctionCommand: _*).inheritIO().start().waitFor()
      if(junctionResult != 0) throw new Exception("mklink failed", cause)
      linkPath
  }.get
}
```

It is executed every time when SBT is started but before any action on your code - before compilation and so on. It does NOT recreate the link on every compilation - only once per SBT start.

The code does following:

- get path to desired folder (and fail if it doesn't exist)
- get path to link (and delete if it exists)
- try to create a new link using Java 7+ API
- if it runs on Windows 7+ and without admin right it will fail. In this case I create a junction using standard but windows-specific tool `mklink /J`

Limits of this solution:

- it will not work on FAT file systems
- *have you seen other limits? let me know!*

Comment: Tested on IDEA 14 & Windows 7

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work quite right for me. I can add the core just fine and the application even finds the classes, but when I try to compile it (the application) it complains that in the core-classes imports can't be found. Like if I have a `import tld.someclass` within `core.someotherclass` and when application imports the `core.someotherclass` it complains that there it can't find `import tld.someclass` (although everything is fine if I just look at the core-package). Maybe you can check again and add the whole .sbt file? I've manually added an unmangedSourceDirectory, that may be the prob

Comment: Also, if you find a way to do it, can you check if it works if "core" has some (native) libraries as a dependency? I would need these as well in the "application".

Comment: Could you look into this again, please?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot review it now. But I hope to have more time in a month.

Comment: Does this problem come in SBT or in IDEA only? Could it be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7992?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible in SBT (but I'd love to hear otherwise).

Here's what I'm doing in IntelliJ to work around this issue:

- Open "application" in IntelliJ; refresh the SBT definition
- Turn off SBT auto-update (file -> settings -> build -> SBT)
- Do file -> new -> module from existing sources, choose the "core" checkout dir, import it from SBT

  - Tick “download sources”, but not “auto-update”
- You should now have both “application” and “core” in the same IntelliJ window (but "application" still depends on a "core" JAR not your live sources)
- Right click on the "application" project in IntelliJ and choose “open module settings”

  - Open the “dependencies” tab
  - Find the "core" SBT dependency(-ies) in the libraries and delete them
  - Add a "module dependency" on the "core" project
- You should manually rebuild the project at this point, as IntelliJ has been known to get confused about classpaths when adding in modules.
- You can now develop with the two projects as a single codebase in IntelliJ

  - Note that SBT command line tools like “sbt test” in "application" will continue to use the "core" JAR and not the locally modified sources
  - (The SBT Build.scala file in "application" still references the "core" JAR by version number)
- When you are ready to commit, you will need to:

  - Commit your changes to "core", update the version number
  - Run "sbt publishLocal" in "core", make a note of the version numbers generated
  - Update the Build.scala file in "application" to reference the new "core" version
  - Run "sbt test" or similar to check that everything works in SBT mode
  - Commit the "application" changes, push both

Answer (score 3):

You could use *ProjectRef*:

```
lazy val my_application = (project in file ("."))
    .aggregate(my_core)
    .dependsOn(my_core)

lazy val my_core = ProjectRef(file("../my_core"), "my_core")
```

Then, regarding the directory structure, `my_application` and `my_core` are siblings.